Trying to retrieve on my frontEnd some account info
I am trying to use a minimalist example to get a feeling of how Solana/Anchor works.
I am using anchor-cli v.0.30 and solana v.1.18.15.
So I followed some basic tutorial to count the amount of time a button is clicked.
Here is the program on the solana explorer : https://explorer.solana.com/address/7cweAkBzN7RhVkPUcL2UC1c4CAE4M6SJ63rwNoU4qRoB?cluster=devnet
Now I am on the vuejs/javascript world and I don't really know how to create the program and execute the simple click instruction and retrieve the count.
I tried the following code and it works for another program, but not mine :
import { useAnchorWallet } from 'solana-wallets-vue';
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { Program, AnchorProvider, Wallet } from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
import { Button } from './anchor/idl';

export async function main(programAdress : string) {
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'));
  const wallet = useAnchorWallet();
  const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet.value as Wallet);
  const program = new PublicKey(programAdress);
  const idl = await Program.fetchIdl<Button>(program, provider);
  
  console.log(idl);
}

main('cndy3Z4yapfJBmL3ShUp5exZKqR3z33thTzeNMm2gRZ')
main('7cweAkBzN7RhVkPUcL2UC1c4CAE4M6SJ63rwNoU4qRoB')

Any ideas on how to unblock this situation?

I've never worked with Vue, but one of the engineers I highly respect wrote a tutorial series you can check out here https://lorisleiva.com/create-a-solana-dapp-from-scratch/scaffolding-the-frontend

This is really helpful, thank you!

I finished this minimal Solana/Anchor project with vueJs if anyone fighting at the moment like me  : https://github.com/Burning-Tiger/SolanaButton
